# Display informations under the X-Axis like in Excel with Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have a problem to display informations in Highcharts under the X-Axis, it should look like in the:

[image]

I tried the Function `exporting.showTable` but it doesnt look like i want it. Thanks for any help.

Best regards

RichieRich

Answer (score 0):

From the Highcharts side, you can start from this template and add a custom HTML table under the chart.

```
xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
    tickWidth: 1,
    offset: 0,
    tickLength: 30
},
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hdjto1zv/

Comment: That is not what i want. I want to display data UNDER the X-Axis. But thx for the try.